# In ruby on rails Dynamic id isn't working for two words but worked perfectly for one word --used bootstrap collapse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am working on the device portion of my project. I have grouped the `brandname` and pass the brand name as an `id`. My problem is that dynamic id isn't working for two words eg. `Hero Honda` but perfectly working for one word eg. `Yamaha`

Code of my controller is:

```
  def index
    @devices = Device.all.group_by(&:brandname)
    @device = current_user.devices.build
  end
```

Here is my code of views

```
 button.btn.btn-sm.btn-outline-info aria-controls="12" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#hello#{device_name}" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" 
          | Details
    .collapse.container.mx-5 id="hello#{device_name}"
          .container.bg-light 
            .row.bg-secondary.p-2.my-2
                .col-3.col-md-3.text-center MAC address
                .col-2.col-md-2.text-center Serial Number
                .col-2.col-md-2.text-center Software
                .col-2.col-md-2.text-center  Number
                .col-1.col-md-1.text-center  Status
              
                           
            - device_data.each do |device|
              .row.py-2
                    .col-3.text-center = device.macaddress
                    .col-2.text-center = device.serialnumber
                    .col-2.text-center = device.softwareversion
                    .col-2.text-center = device.IMEInumber
                    .col-1.text-center = device.status
                    .col-2.text-center = device.id
```

[Here I present the console of browser how program takes dynamic id.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5A7F.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML id tag cannot have whitespaces. So I'd suggest you to first transform your `brandname` to make it so that it does not contain whitespaces. Eg: You can convert your spaces into `-` or `_`.

```
id="hello-#{device_name.parameterize}"
# => hello-hero-honda
```

or

```
id="hello_#{device_name.parameterize.underscore}"
# => hello_hero_honda
```

---

*Note: Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.* ([Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id))

So camelCase seems like a better option.

```
id="hello#{device_name.parameterize.underscore.camelize}"
# => helloHeroHonda
```